# Convert Multiple character columns to Date time and then do row means

Tags: python, r

I have 30 columns in `data-frame` and need to convert columns from 2 to 30 from characters to datetime.
Further I also need to keep just time part in these columns and take the average (row means) of each row  in new column.

I tried doing like below but it's only giving date part; the time part is being converted to `00:00:00` . I tried using different solutions posted on various threads but did not get desired o/p.

```
Data[ ,2:3] <- lapply(Data[ 2:3], as.Date , format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Sample data -

```
Data - 

Job  2021-05-31           2021-05-30           2021-05-29 
ABC  2021-05-31 03:35:32  2021-05-30 02:25:26  2021-05-29 04:40:56
Def  2021-05-31 04:25:43  2021-05-30 03:23:44  2021-05-29 05:45:23
Xyz  2021-05-31 02:25:34  2021-05-30 02:23:44  2021-05-29 03:45:23

Expected Output is 

Job   2021-05-31   2021-05-30   2021-05-29   Avg_time 
ABC   03:35:32     02:25:26     04:40:56     03:33:58
Def   04:25:43     03:23:44     05:45:23     04:31:37
Xyz   02:25:34     02:23:44     03:45:23     02:51:34
```

Comment: Please provide data in a reproducible format using `dput(head(Data))`. Also show expected output for the data shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you can try in base R.

First, you can convert your character values to dates and times through `as.POSIXct`. Then, you can store via `format` the times only from the result.

```
df <- as.data.frame(
  lapply(
    lapply(
      dat[-1, 2:4], 
      as.POSIXct, 
      format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    ),
    format,
    "%H:%M:%S"
  )
)
```

The resultant `df` is:

```
        V2       V3       V4
1 03:35:32 02:25:26 04:40:56
2 04:25:43 03:23:44 05:45:23
3 02:25:34 02:23:44 03:45:23
```

To compute the mean times, you can use `strptime` to return to prior format, compute the mean, and then go back to time-only format.

```
df$avg_time <- apply(
  df,
  1,
  function(x) {
    format(mean(strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S")), "%H:%M:%S")
  }
)
```

Final `df` would look like this:

```
        V2       V3       V4 avg_time
1 03:35:32 02:25:26 04:40:56 03:33:58
2 04:25:43 03:23:44 05:45:23 04:31:36
3 02:25:34 02:23:44 03:45:23 02:51:33
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Apologies for delayed response , The solution you provided is working . Thanks for helping . I have got some null values in the columns , which I am dealing as below 

df$avg_time <- apply(
  df,
  1,
  function(x) {
    format(mean(strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S"),na.rm=TRUE), "%H:%M:%S")
  }
)

Comment: I am further trying to get Standard deviation (sd)  on rows, however apply(df [,-1], 1, sd,na.rm=TRUE) is only giving NULL values. Can you suggest how to achieve sd on rows?

Comment: Try something like `df$sd_time <- apply(
  df[,1:3],
  1,
  function(x) {
    sd(strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S"), na.rm = T)
  }
)` with your above example --- does that give you what you need?

Comment: The mean works , however  SD is not working . It throws below error -
R : Error: is.atomic(x) is not TRUE  ... I did try changing the columns from string to datetime , but still its throwing the same error

Comment: I’m having trouble reproducing your error. When I tried this code using your data it worked for me. Can you try to edit your question with what code you used so I can reproduce? To share your data, use dput() function and copy/paste the result. Alternatively, you can always try posting a new question if you want to get more attention from other people.

Answer (score 0):

Here is suggestion using a `tidyverse` approach. I used `hms` package to work with time data. `str_trim()` in `change_time()` is to remove the padding spaces in the first row. Please ignore that if there is are spaces in your data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hms)

dat <- read.table(
  text = "
  Job| 2021-05-31          |2021-05-30          |2021-05-29 
ABC| 2021-05-31 03:35:32 |2021-05-30 02:25:26 |2021-05-29 04:40:56
Def| 2021-05-31 04:25:43 |2021-05-30 03:23:44 |2021-05-29 05:45:23
Xyz| 2021-05-31 02:25:34 |2021-05-30 02:23:44 |2021-05-29 03:45:23",
header = FALSE, sep = "|"
)

change_time <- function(x) {
  str_trim(x) %>% 
    if_else(str_length(.) == 10, paste(., "00:00:00"), .) %>% 
    str_sub(., 12)
}

dat1 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(across(-V1, list(time = change_time)),
         across(ends_with("time"), hms::as_hms)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    average_time = mean(c_across(ends_with("time"))),
    average_time = as_hms(round(average_time))
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

dat1
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Zaw,
Thank you so much for  helping out.  but I should have updated earlier. that my org do- not have access to all packages.  tidyverse and hms is not available :(